# Some pretty fixed width font for Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, fonts, text-editors

With Mac, I like the font of Menlo for text editors. With PC, it's hard for me to find some pretty fixed with font, and I don't like the Courier font that I have to use for emEditor.

Could you recommend me some fixed width font that I can download and use for PC? I expect menlo equivalent somewhere, and it would be great if I can learn how to use the font with emacs/win32.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apple Menlo is basically identical to DejaVu Sans Mono ([evidence here](http://9-bits.com/post/123940811/menlo-font-macosx)), both of which are based on Bitstream Vera Mono. The Deja Vu fonts have a free license, and can be used or modified or whatever.
[Download it here.](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page)

(Oops, sorry for the duplicate. I'll make up for it by mentioning some others I like...

[Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) (though Windows 7's consolas is pretty much the same)

[Anonymous Pro](http://www.ms-studio.com/FontSales/anonymouspro.html)

[Droid Sans Mono](http://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/14/droid-font-family-courtesy-of-google-ascender)

[BPmono](http://www.dafont.com/bpmono.font)

[LuxiMono](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Luxi-Mono)
)

Comment: +1 for anonymous pro, I use it for programming. Fine font.

Comment: A small thing--Consolas and Inconsolata are different enough to me that I strongly prefer the latter over the former and even over any monospaced font I have found.

Answer (score 3):

Its not perfect - but I use DejaVu Sans Mono. Its neat and tidy, and I've found one of the easiest fonts to stare at for hours on end.

According to http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=653948, Menlo is a modification of Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, so that might suit your needs.

The DejaVu family is available at http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page
The Bitsteam family is available at http://www.dafont.com/bitstream-vera-mono.font

Both are open source fonts and can be freely downloaded and used.

Comment: Sans as in sans serif? rather than sans as in without?

Comment: Yep - Sans Serif.

Comment: ok.. just to correct myself.. the sans in sans serif also means without. (without serifs).. n yeah,, DejaVu Sans (ie Sans Serif) Mono

Answer (score 3):

There is a discussion [here](http://typophile.com/node/58625) about Menlo that mentions Vera Sans Mono and Prima Sans Mono, you could try getting hold of those (the other answer has a link, which I was about to post).

This little search brings up some resources I've used before.

http://www.google.com/search?q=nice+programming+font

Also, Jeff Atwood has a post about Consolas [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/consolas-and-cleartype.html), where he mentions using Monaco for every ClearType monospace font he can, and the comments have links to other programming fonts. Jeff has a more complete overview of programming fonts [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/progamming-fonts.html), with visuals of course.

Comment: Between these three posts I think you've got enough!